# Creating generic array in Java via unchecked type-cast

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting, type-safety

If I have a generic class `Foo<Bar>`, I am not allowed to create an array as follows:

```
Bar[] bars = new Bar[];
```

(This will cause the error "Cannot create a generic array of Bar").

But, as suggested by *dimo414* in an answer to [this question (Java how to: Generic Array creation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation),  I can do the following:

```
Bar[] bars = (Bar[]) new Object[];
```

(This will "only" generate a warning: "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object[] to Bar[]").

In the comments responding to *dimo414*'s answer, some people claim that using this construct can cause problems in certain situations and others say it's fine, as the only reference to the array is `bars`, which is of the desired type already.

I'm a little confused in which cases this is OK and in which cases it can run me into trouble. The comments by *newacct* and *Aaron McDaid*, for example, seem to directly contradict each other. Unfortunately the comment stream in the original question simply ends with the unanswered "Why is this 'no longer correct'?", so I decided to make a new question for it:

If the `bars`-array only ever contains entries of type `Bar`, could there still be any run-time issues when using the array or its entries? Or is the only danger, that at run-time I could technically cast the array to something else (like `String[]`), which would then allow me to fill it with values of a type other than `Bar`?

I know I can use `Array.newInstance(...)` instead, but I am specifically interested in the type-casting construct above, since, for example, in GWT the `newInstance(...)`-option isn't available.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since I was mentioned in the question, I will chime in.

Basically, it will not cause any problems if you don't expose this array variable to the outside of the class. (kinda like, What happens in Vegas stays in Vegas.)

The actual runtime type of the array is `Object[]`. So putting it into a variable of type `Bar[]` is effectively a "lie", since `Object[]` is not a subtype of `Bar[]` (unless `Object` is `Bar`). However, this lie is okay if it stays inside the class, since `Bar` is erased to `Object` inside the class. (The lower bound of `Bar` is `Object` in this question. In a case where the lower bound of `Bar` is something else, replace all occurrences of `Object` in this discussion with whatever that bound is.) However, if this lie gets somehow exposed to the outside (the simplest example is returning the `bars` variable directly as type `Bar[]`, then it will cause problems.

To understand what is really going on, it is instructive to look at the code with and without generics. Any generics program can be re-written into an equivalent non-generics program, simply by removing generics and inserting casts in the right place. This transformation is called *type erasure*.

We consider a simple implementation of `Foo<Bar>`, with methods for getting and setting particular elements in the array, as well as a method for getting the whole array:

```
class Foo<Bar> {
    Bar[] bars = (Bar[])new Object[5];
    public Bar get(int i) {
        return bars[i];
    }
    public void set(int i, Bar x) {
        bars[i] = x;
    }
    public Bar[] getArray() {
        return bars;
    }
}

// in some method somewhere:
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>();
foo.set(2, "hello");
String other = foo.get(3);
String[] allStrings = foo.getArray();
```

After type erasure, this becomes:

```
class Foo {
    Object[] bars = new Object[5];
    public Object get(int i) {
        return bars[i];
    }
    public void set(int i, Object x) {
        bars[i] = x;
    }
    public Object[] getArray() {
        return bars;
    }
}

// in some method somewhere:
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.set(2, "hello");
String other = (String)foo.get(3);
String[] allStrings = (String[])foo.getArray();
```

So there are no casts inside the class anymore. However, there are casts in the calling code -- when getting one element, and getting the entire array. The cast to get one element should not fail, because the only things we can put into the array are `Bar`, so the only things we can get out are also `Bar`. However, the cast when getting the entire array, that will fail, since the array has actual runtime type `Object[]`.

Written non-generically, what is happening and the problem become much more apparent. What is especially troubling is that the cast failure does not happen in the class where we wrote the cast in generics -- it happens in someone else's code that uses our class. And that other person's code is completely safe and innocent. It also does not happen at the time where we did our cast in the generics code -- it happens later, when someone calls `getArray()`, without warning.

If we didn't have this `getArray()` method, then this class would be safe. With this method, it is unsafe. What characteristic makes it unsafe? It returns `bars` as type `Bar[]`, which depends on the "lie" we made earlier. Since the lie is not true, it causes problems. If the method had instead returned the array as type `Object[]`, then it would be safe, since it does not depend on the "lie".

People will tell you to not do such a cast like this, because it causes cast exceptions in unexpected places as seen above, not in the original place where the unchecked cast was. The compiler will not warn you that `getArray()` is unsafe (because from its point of view, given the types you told it, it is safe). Thus it depends on the programmer to be diligent about this pitfall and not to use it in an unsafe way.

However, I would argue that this is not a big concern in practice. Any well-designed API will never expose internal instance variables to the outside. (Even if there is a method to return the contents as an array, it would not return the internal variable directly; it would copy it, to prevent outside code from modifying the array directly.) So no method will be implemented like `getArray()` is anyway.

Comment: Hey! :) Awesome! It's helpful to actually think about what the entire Foo-class looks like after type erasure and where exactly the type-casts happen. For example, I had been under the (false) assumption that the (Bar)-casts happen inside the Foo-class rather than where it's called. But it definitely does make more sense this way. What still seems a little weird to me, though, is the fact that `Object bar = foo.getArray()[0]` will fail, while `for (Object bar: foo.getArray())` works fine... But I guess that's just caused by where and how the two statements cast the array... Thanks! +1, v´

Answer (score 4):

As opposed to lists, Java's array types are *reified*, which means that the *runtime type* of `Object[]` is distinct from `String[]`. Therefore, when you write

```
Bar[] bars = (Bar[]) new Object[];
```

you have created an array of runtime type `Object[]` and have "cast" it to `Bar[]`. I say "cast" within quotes because this is not a real checked-cast operation: it is just a compile-time directive which allows you to assign an `Object[]` into a variable of type `Bar[]`. Naturally, this opens the door to all kinds of runtime type errors. Whether it will actually create the errors is entirely up to your programming prowess and attentiveness. Therefore, if you feel up to it, then it is OK to do it; if you don't or this code is a part of a larger project with many developers, then it is a dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've played with this construct for a bit and it can be a REAL mess.

I think the answer to my question is: Everything works fine as long as you always handle the array as generic. But as soon as you try to treat it in a non-generic way, there's trouble. Let me give a couple of examples:

- Inside `Foo<Bar>`, I can create the array as shown and work with it just fine. This is because (if I understand correctly) the compiler "erases" the `Bar`-type and simply turns it into `Object` everywhere. So essentially inside `Foo<Bar>` you are just handling an `Object[]`, which is fine.
- But if you have a function like this inside `Foo<Bar>`, which provides access to the array:

  ```java
  public Bar[] getBars(Bar bar) {
      Bar[] result = (Bar[]) new Object[1];
      result[0] = bar;
      return result;
  }
  ```

  you can run into some serious issues, if you use it somewhere else. Here are some examples of the craziness (most of it actually makes sense, but it seems crazy at first sight) you get:

  - `String[] bars = new Foo<String>().getBars("Hello World");`

    will cause *java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;*
  - `for (String bar: new Foo<String>().getBars("Hello World"))`

    will also cause the same *java.lang.ClassCastException*
  - but

    ```java
    for (Object bar: new Foo<String>().getBars("Hello World"))
        System.out.println((String) bar);
    ```

    works...
  - Here's one that doesn't make sense to me:

    ```java
    String bar = new Foo<String>().getBars("Hello World")[0];
    ```

    will cause the *java.lang.ClassCastException*, too, even though I'm not assigning it to a String[] anywhere.
  - Even

    ```java
    Object bar = new Foo<String>().getBars("Hello World")[0];
    ```

    will cause the same *java.lang.ClassCastException*!
  - Only

    ```java
    Object[] temp = new Foo<String>().getBars("Hello World");
    String bar = (String) temp[0];
    ```

    works...

  and **none** of these throw any compile-time errors, by the way.
- Now, if you have another generic class, though:

  ```java
  class Baz<Bar> {
      Bar getFirstBar(Bar bar) {
          Bar[] bars = new Foo<Bar>().getBars(bar);
          return bars[0];
      }
  }
  ```

  The following works just fine:

  ```java
  String bar = new Baz<String>().getFirstBar("Hello World");
  ```

Most of this makes sense, once you realize that, after type-erasure, the `getBars(...)`-function actually returns an `Object[]`, independent of `Bar`. This is why you can't (at runtime) assign the return value to a `String[]` without generating an exception, even if `Bar` was set as `String`. Why this prevents you to index into the array without first casting it back to an `Object[]` beats me, though. The reason why things work fine in the `Baz<Bar>`-class is that the `Bar[]` there will also be turned into an `Object[]`, independent of `Bar`. Thus, this would be equivalent to casting the array to `Object[]`, then indexing it, and then casting the returned entry back to `String`.

Overall, after seeing this, I'm definitely convinced that using this way to create arrays is a really bad idea, unless you don't ever return the array to anywhere outside your generic class. For my purposes, I'll be using a `Collection<...>` instead of an array.

Comment: Aside: Does anyone know how I can enable syntax-highlighting in the code-blocks immediately following the bullet-point? Please feel free to edit the answer or let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works okay until you want to use something in that array as it would of type `Bar` (or whatever type you initialize the generic class with) and not as an `Object` which it really is. For example having the method:

```
<T> void init(T t) {
    T[] ts = (T[]) new Object[2];
    ts[0] = t;
    System.out.println(ts[0]);
}
```

seems to work okay for all types. If you change it to:

```
<T> T[] init(T t) {
    T[] ts = (T[]) new Object[2];
    ts[0] = t;
    System.out.println(ts[0]);
    return ts;
}
```

and call it with

```
init("asdf");
```

it still works fine; but when you want to really use the real T[] array (which should be String[] in the above example):

```
String[] strings = init("asfd");
```

then you have a problem, since `Object[]` and `String[]` are two distinct classes and what you have is `Object[]` so a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

The problem arises more quickly if you try a bounded generic type:

```
<T extends Runnable> void init(T t) {
    T[] ts = (T[]) new Object[2];
    ts[0] = t;
    System.out.println(ts[0]);
    ts[0].run();
}
```

As a good practice, try avoiding using generics and arrays since they do not mix very well together.

Answer (score 0):

The cast:

```
  Bar[] bars = (Bar[]) new Object[];
```

is an operation that will happen at runtime. If the runtime type of `Bar[]` is anything other than `Object[]` then this will generate a `ClassCastException`.

Therefore, if you place bounds on `Bar` as in `<Bar extends Something>` it will fail. This is because the runtime type of `Bar` will be `Something`. If `Bar` doesn't have any upper bounds then it's type will be erased to `Object` and the compiler will generate all the relevant casts for placing objects into the array or for reading from it.

If you try to assign `bars` to something with a runtime type that isn't `Object[]` (e.g `String[] z = bars`) then the operation will fail. The compiler warns you about this usecase with the "unchecked cast" warning. So the following will fail even though it compiles with a warning:

```
class Foo<Bar> {
    Bar[] get() {
       return (Bar[])new Object[1];
    }
}
void test() {
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>();
    String[] z = foo.get();
}
```