# java generics return an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

edit: I don't see how the other question answers mine. I already have an explicit cast (E[]) which the author of the other question doesn't have. 
I also tried something like seq1 = (Integer[]) iw.result(); but that doesn't work either.

I have the following code:

```
public class Something<E extends Comparable<E>> {
E[] seq;
public Something() {
    seq = (E[]) new Object[100];
}

public E[] result() {
    return sequence;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Something<Integer> iw = new Something<Integer>();
    Integer[] seq1 = new Integer[100];
    seq1 = iw.result();
}}
```

I get an errormessage in the way of: [Object can't be cast to [Comparable

So I change the Something-Constructor to:

```
seq = (E[]) new Comparable[100];
```

Now I get an errormessage in the way of: [Comparable can't be cast to [Integer

Is there any way to make the above code work? I know I would be better off working with Collections here, but I'm just curious what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Well, obviously, neither `Object[]` nor `Comparable[]` are `Integer[]`s, so you'll never be able to assign one to the other. The type safety warning you get with the cast to `E[]` should hint at that problem. You can't create a array based on the generic parameter is what the duplicate is trying to tell you. You can use the the elements in the array as if they were generic but you'll never be able to use the array as an array of the concrete type argument.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4221845/438154) proposes a solution if you already have an array of the type you want (and its corresponding `Class` object). This is what `ArrayList` does. You may want to look at its source code.

Comment: I found a better duplicate for you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  I'm not so sure I'm satisfied with that as a dupe, either.  The whole thing waxes philosophical about what it means to create generic arrays, but I don't feel like it addresses this concern directly.

Comment: Why not just `Something<E>`?

Comment: @Warkst:  That loses the desired bound to `Comparable`.  While I don't know the *rationale* for stuffing a bunch of comparable objects into an array, it's still very much desired.

Comment: hmmm can't seq=new E[100] work ?

Comment: @niceman:  [**No.**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/529085/1079354)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues here.

First, that's not an unbounded generic parameter, that's got a bound of `Comparable<E>` attached to it.

During type erasure, with your class declared as:

```
public class Something<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    E[] seq;
}
```

...`E` is bound to `Comparable`.

```
public class Something {
    Comparable[] seq;
}
```

*This* is why your casting isn't going to work, since an `Object` is not a `Comparable`.  You would want to use `new Comparable` instead.

```
public class Something<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    E[] seq;

    public Something() {
        seq = (E[]) new Comparable[100];
    }
}
```

Now, Java is and *should* break on the last two statements.

```
Integer[] seq1 = new Integer[100];
seq1 = iw.result();
```

`iw.result()` is bound to `Comparable[]`, not `Integer[]`. A `Comparable[]` can never become an `Integer[]`.

You can do this instead to eschew the `ClassCastException` instead:

```
Comparable[] seq1 = new Integer[100];
```

This will work since an `Integer` is `Comparable`.  This is due to the fact that arrays are covariant (that is to say, an `Integer[]` is a subtype of a `Comparable[]`).

Comment: I hate that you've done this. Your answer doesn't provide anything new. The [question linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831896/creating-generic-array-in-java-via-unchecked-type-cast) and its answers already explain all of this.

Comment: It didn't feel like it explained it clearly enough to me, so that's why I did it.  I'm sorry that you don't agree with it, but I'm not entirely remorseful that I've answered the question in this way.