# Why does the JVM allow be to pass a B[] to a method that expects an A[]?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic test class:

```
public class BrokenGenerics<T> {

    private T[] genericTypeArray;

    public BrokenGenerics(T... initArray) {
        genericTypeArray = initArray;
    }

    public void setArray(T[] newArray) {
        genericTypeArray = newArray;
    }

    public T get(int idx) {
        return genericTypeArray[idx];
    }

    public Class getType() {
        return genericTypeArray.getClass().getComponentType();
    }



    public static boolean breakThis(BrokenGenerics any) {
        any.setArray(new B[]{new B(2)});
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrokenGenerics<A> aBreaker = new BrokenGenerics<A>(new A("1"));
        System.out.println(aBreaker.get(0));
        System.out.println(aBreaker.getType());
        breakThis(aBreaker);
        System.out.println(aBreaker.get(0));
        System.out.println(aBreaker.getType());
    }

    private static class A {

        public String val;

        public A(String init) {
            val = init;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "A value: " + val;
        }
    }

    private static class B {

        public int val;

        public B(int init) {
            val = init;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "B value: " + val;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this output, and **no errors**:

```
A value: 1
class BrokenGenerics$A
B value: 2
class BrokenGenerics$B
```

Now, I understand why this compiles; it can't know at compile-time that `breakThis` is being passed a generic of a bad type. However, once it runs the line `any.setArray(new B[]{new B(2)});`, **shouldn't it throw a `ClassCastException` (NOTE THAT IT DOES NOT! Try it yourself!) because I'm trying to pass a `B[]` to a method that expects an `A[]`?** And after that, why does it allow me to `get()` back the `B`?

Comment: I'm sure the compiler issues a warning. It can't do much else, since `T` is `Object` during runtime.

Comment: @Kayaman the compiler also doesn't issue any warnings. I get a green on my code! No warnings or errors at compile or runtime.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero It's impossible that you're not getting any warnings.  At the very least, you should get a raw type warning for `public static boolean breakThis(BrokenGenerics any) {`.

Comment: @Powerlord have you put it into your IDE and gotten a warning? Perhaps my IDE just doesn't show me them.

Comment: @SoltiriosDelimanolis How is this a duplicate? Can you explain to me?

Comment: @Makoto Please re-read my question. My problem is that I am _**NOT**_ getting a `ClassCastException`. For instance, I say "Why does the JVM _**allow**_ me to pass [...]", and I ask "_**shouldn't it**_ throw a `ClassCastException` [...]?"

Comment: Okay.  Fair point.  I'm not as convinced of the duplicality now either.  You'd get a `ClassCastException` if you were *adding* elements of different types together, but in this case you're completely blowing away the array.

Comment: Concerning _because I'm trying to pass a `B[]` to a method that expects an `A[]`_, the duplicate does address this. The method isn't expecting an `A[]` since it's the generic parameter is erased, since the type of the target reference expression is raw.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Granted, but even after knowing that type-erasure allows this to be compiled, I was still perplexed that nothing stopped it from running.

Comment: Ironically enough, the answer you've accepted provides nothing new. Everything it explains was already in the canonical duplicate.

Comment: Your second question _why does it allow me to `get()` back the `B`_ might not be in the duplicate, but it can be inferred. The accepted answer here doesn't address that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), `T` will be turned into `Object` since you didn't specify a bound on `T`. So, there is no problem at runtime assigning any type of array to `genericTypeArray`, which is now of type `Object[]` or calling the function `setArray(...)`, which now also accepts an argument of type `Object[]`. Also, your `get(...)` method will simply return an `Object`.

Trouble starts when you access elements in the array with a wrong type expectation, since this might lead to (implicit or explicit) illegal type casts, for example by assigning the value returned by `get(...)` to a variable of type `A`.

You can also get a run-time ClassCastException if you try to type-cast the array itself, but, in my experience, that is a case that tends to come up less often, although it can be very obscure to find or even understand if it does happen. You can find some examples below.

All generics-checking happens only at compile-time. And if you use [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), these checks can not be performed rigorously, and thus the best the compiler can do is to issue a warning to let you know that you are giving up an opportunity for more meaningful checks by omitting the type argument.

Eclipse with its standard settings (and probably the java compiler with the correct flags) shows these warnings for your code:

- "Class is a raw type" where you define `getType()` (somewhat unrelated to your question)
- "BrokenGenerics is a raw type" where you define `breakThis(...)`
- "Type safety: The method setArray(Object[]) belongs to the raw type
  BrokenGenerics" where you call `setArray(...)` inside `breakThis(...)`.

***Examples for causing ClassCastException due to illegal type-cast of the array:***

You can get ClassCastExceptions at runtime if you expose the array to the outside world (which can often be a dangerous thing to do, so I try to avoid it) by adding the following to `BrokenGenerics<T>`:

```
public T[] getArray() {
    return genericTypeArray;
}
```

If you then change your main method to:

```
BrokenGenerics<A> aBreaker = new BrokenGenerics<A>(new A("1"));
A[] array = aBreaker.getArray();
System.out.println(array[0]);
System.out.println(aBreaker.getType());
breakThis(aBreaker);
array = aBreaker.getArray(); // ClassCastException here!
System.out.println(array[0]);
System.out.println(aBreaker.getType());
```

You get the ClassCastException at runtime at the indicated position due to a cast of the array itself rather than one of its elements.

The same thing can also happen if you set the variable `genericTypeArray` to `protected` and use it from code that subclasses your generic class with a fixed type argument:

```
private static class C extends BrokenGenerics<A> {

    public C(A... initArray) {
        super(initArray);
    }

    public void printFirst() {
        A[] result = genericTypeArray; // ClassCastException here!
        System.out.println(result[0]);
    }
}
```

To trigger the exception, add the following to you main method:

```
C cBreaker = new C(new A("1"));
cBreaker.printFirst();
breakThis(cBreaker);
cBreaker.printFirst();
```

Imagine this case coming up in a bigger project... How on earth would you even begin to understand how **that** line of code could possible fail?!? :) Especially since the stack trace might be of very little help trying to find the `breakThis(...)` call that is actually responsible for the error.

For more in-depth example cases, you can take a look at [some tests I did a little while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17833216/1217178).

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero It's not that Java arrays are abstracted from the type they hold, it's that Generics are abstracted from the type they hold.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero I'm still learning new things about the intricate details of generics every day. It's quite amazing how many strange implications can arise from the erasure approach. Here's something I learned from the generics-ninjas here on SO, which might also be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831896/creating-generic-array-in-java-via-unchecked-type-cast

Comment: On a side note, as a general rule Collections (`Collection`, `List`, `Set`, `Map`) work better with generics than Arrays do.

Comment: @Powerlord but don't those have internal arrays powering them?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero They do, and, in fact, by accessing Collections with raw types, you can blow them up just like you can with your code example. :)

Comment: The reification that arrays have can be... tricky to work around in generics.  Joshua Bloch talks about this a bit in Effective Java: Second Edition, pg 119.  This is part of the [free chapter of the book posted online](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~mmh/APD/bloch/generics.pdf).  Which happens to be the chapter on Generics.  It has some other interesting stuff about Generics as well.

Answer (score 2):

> shouldn't it throw a `ClassCastException` because I'm trying to pass a `B[]` to a method that expects an `A[]`?

No. As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) explains, your invocation of `setArray` in

```
public static boolean breakThis(BrokenGenerics any) {
    any.setArray(new B[]{new B(2)});
    return false;
}
```

is done on a reference expression of the raw type `BrokenGenerics`. When interacting with raw types, all corresponding generic parameters are erased. So `setArray` is actually expecting a `Object[]`. [A `B[]` is a `Object[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant).

> why does it allow me to `get()` back the `B`?

Assuming you're asking about this

```
System.out.println(aBreaker.get(0));
```

[`PrintStream#println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) expects an `Object`, not an `A`. As such, there is no reason for the compiler to insert a cast here. Since there is no cast, there is no `ClassCastException`.

If you had instead done

```
A a = aBreaker.get(0);
```

or had a method like

```
void println(A a) {}
...
println(aBreaker.get(0));
```

then these would cause `ClassCastException`. In other words, the compiler will insert a cast ([`checkcast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.checkcast)) anywhere a type needs to be converted from a generic type parameter. That was not the case with `PrintStream#println`.

Similarly,

```
System.out.println(aBreaker.getType());
```

doesn't even involve the generic parameter declared in `BrokenGenerics`

```
public Class getType() {...}
```

and also returns a value of the raw type `Class`. The compiler has no reason to add a `checkcast` to `A`.

Comment: I suppose I misworded my second question. I was more interested why the line `return genericTypeArray[idx];` ran just fine. `get()` returns a `T`, right? And at runtime, doesn't it know that when I call `get()`, I want an `A` back, but it gave me a `B`? That said, I think I understand, now, that it just abstracts to being the supertype of `T` (`Object`), and that's why it works.