# In java generic programming, is the Object class upper bound or lower bound of the parameter type without wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-types

when answering the question [Creating generic array in Java via unchecked type-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831896/creating-generic-array-in-java-via-unchecked-type-cast?answertab=votes#tab-top), newacct said

> (The lower bound of Bar is Object in this question. In a case where the lower bound of Bar is something else, replace all occurrences of Object in this discussion with whatever that bound is.)

Here is newacct's code:

```
class Foo<Bar> {
    Bar[] bars = (Bar[])new Object[5];
    public Bar get(int i) {
        return bars[i];
    }
    public void set(int i, Bar x) {
        bars[i] = x;
    }
    public Bar[] getArray() {
        return bars;
    }
}
```

I wonder whether `Object` is the upper bound or lower bound of `Bar`. I think that `Foo<Bar>` is short for `Foo<Bar extends Object>`, so Object should be the upper bound of `Bar`, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Given a type variable declaration `<T extends TypeName>`, `TypeName` is the upper bound of `T`. Technically, I think it's just the *bound*, since the upper/lower distinction is [only made for wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1). Additionally, [if no bound is specified, then `Object` is assumed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4), so you're right that `Object` is the bound of `Bar` in the example.

I think newacct just misspoke when they wrote the answer and meant to say 'upper bound' instead of 'lower bound'.

*Edit*: Also, when talking about the particular construct in the referenced Q&A, it's useful to point out that [the erasure of a type variable is the erasure of its left-most bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) which is the importance of replacing the element type used for the array creation with the type used in the bound. For example, given a complex type variable declaration `<T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable>`, the erasure of `T` would be `Comparable`, so you would use `Comparable[]` or `Comparable<?>[]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can define the lower bound as follows in generics as well.

```
class Foo<T extends Bar> {
T[] bars = (T[])new Object[5];
public T get(int i) {
    return bars[i];
}
public void set(int i, Bar x) {
    bars[i] = x;
}
public T[] getArray() {
    return bars;
}
```

}

So you can create a Foo object with any class that extends Bar.

No, you cannot use Object typed instances and lower bound is **Bar** and upper bound is **any class that extends Bar class**.